# NODE.JS Error: Failed to lookup view "/articles/[object Object]" in views directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Hello all I am currently working with creating a comment system for my website. However I get an error as in the title.
my form

```js
<form action="/comments" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="article_id" id="article_id" value="<%= article._id %>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<%= currentUser._id %>" />
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea required name="content" id="content" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                  textarea = document.querySelector("#post");
                  textarea.addEventListener('input', autoResize, false);

                  function autoResize() {
                    this.style.height = 'auto';
                    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
                  }
                </script>
</form>
```

here is the code processing the form

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const path = require('path')
const Article = require('./../models/article')
const Comment = require('./../models/comment')
const User = require('./../models/user')

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body.post)
  req.comment = new Comment()
  let comment = req.comment
  let user =  await User.findOne(req.body.user_id)
  let article = await Article.findOne(req.body.article_id)
  comment.content = req.body.content
  comment.userName = req.user.name
  user.comments.push(comment._id)
  article.comments.push(comment._id)
  try {
    article = await article.save()
    comment = await comment.save()
    res.redirect(`/articles/${article.slug}`)
  } catch (e) {
    res.render(`/articles/${path}`, { article: article })
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

I have determined that node is not transferring req.body.content correctly as it appears as undefined when I try to process the request. How would I be able to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: In this line "res.render(`/articles/${path}`" , path is an object when you do `const path = require('path')` at top of the file. To populate req.body, you need to use a middleware to parse incoming requests. If you use json format, it is `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: Hi Đăng, I am able to grab some items from the form just fine but the text area doesn't seem to be passing. I had tried your recommended action but it did not work.